# "repository not found" when trying to clone microsoft autogen repository

Tags: github

I'm trying to run an AutoGen examples and none of them let me clone.

For example:

https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/tree/main/website

```
$ git clone https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/tree/main/website
Cloning into 'website'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/microsoft/autogen/tree/main/website/' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git `clone --filter` and `git sparse-checkout` to only clone the contents of a specific folder locally.

```
git clone -n --depth=1 --filter=tree:0 https://github.com/microsoft/autogen
cd autogen
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone website
git checkout
```